# Unable to login after creating a post

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

So, I've been scratching my head for over a day about this problem. My app supports signup, signin, creating a post. What I have noticed is that the user who doesn't have a post can login successfully any time. But those who have posts cannot login after.

Here's how it looks.

```
case 1
I register with Jim -> jim is stored in the db -> login with jim(success) -> logout(works fine) and again login(works fine)

case 2
I register with Jim -> jim is stored in the db -> login with jim(success) -> makes a post -> post shows in his feed(success) -> logout(works fine) and again try to login(failed)
```

The error is->

`POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/login 402 (Payment Required)`

It's not even entering the login controller when a user who has post(s) try to login. It's working successfully for the user who has no post(s). It's confusing me.

Here's the code:

```js
    registerUser: (req, res) => {
        console.log("inside register user")
        const { username, email, password } = req.body
        User.create(req.body, (err, createdUser) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({ error: "Server error occurred" })
            } else if (!username || !email || !password) {
                return res.status(400).json({ message: "Username, email and password are must" })
            } else if (!validator.isEmail(email)) {
                return res.status(400).json({ message: "Invaid email" })
            } else if (password.length < 6) {
                return res.status(400).json({ message: "Password should be of at least 6 characters" })
            }
            else {
                return res.status(200).json({ user: createdUser })
            }
        })
    },

    loginUser: async (req, res, next) => {
        console.log("inside login controller")
        const { email, password } = req.body

        if (!email || !password) {
            return res.status(400).json({ message: "Email and password are must" })
        }

        await User.findOne({ email }, (err, user) => {
            if (err) {
                return next(err)
            } else if (!validator.isEmail(email)) { 
                return res.status(400).json({ message: "Invalid email" })
            } else if (!user) {
                return res.status(402).json({ error: "User not found" })
            } else if (!user.confirmPassword(password)) {
                return res.status(402).json({ error: "incorrect password" })
            } 

            // generate token here
            const token = auth.signToken({ userId: user._id })
            // const token = auth.signToken({ email })

            res.status(200).json({ user, token })
            // next()
        })
    }
```

`newPost controller`

```js
newPost: (req, res) => {

    const data = {
      title: req.body.title,
      content: req.body.content,
      user: req.user.userId
    }

    Post.create(data, (err, newPost) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({ error: err })
      } else if (!newPost) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: "No Post found" })
      } else if (newPost) {
        User.findById(req.user.userId, (err, user) => {
          user.posts.push(newPost._id) //pushing posts documnet objectid to the post array of the user document
          user
            .save()
            .then(() => {
              return res.json(200).json({ user })
            })
            .catch(err => {
              return res.status(500).json({ error: err })
            })
        })
      }
    })
  }
```

I also checked in postman by going to the route `/users/login` and entering the email and password, but it's saying `incorrect password`. It's returning the return from

```js
else if (!user.confirmPassword(password)) {
       return res.status(402).json({ error: "incorrect password" })
 }
```

If I change the above to `({ error: err})`, it's returning in the response:

```js
{
    "error": null
}
```

`Update`

```js
       User.findById(req.user.userId, (err, user) => {
          console.log("user before save", user)
          user.gratitudes.push(newGratitude._id) //pushing posts documnet objectid to the post array of the user document
          user
            .save()
            .then(() => {
              // return res.json(200).json({ user })
              console.log("user after saving", user)
            })
            .catch(err => {
              return res.status(500).json({ error: err })
            })
        )
```

So, I did this and consoles

```js
user before saving => { posts: [],
  _id: 5e78c76381327761329b8dc6,
  username: 'king123',
  email: 'king123@gmail.com',
  password: '$2b$10$CnWib5AMxw1qv5RnBdEisOXUq9X3lqqOMH3HWO3DlWf.iB2Ke8GLS',
  createdAt: 2020-03-23T14:27:47.820Z,
  updatedAt: 2020-03-23T14:27:47.820Z,
  __v: 0 }


user after saving =>  { posts: [ 5e78c77a81327761329b8dc7 ],
  _id: 5e78c76381327761329b8dc6,
  username: 'king123',
  email: 'king123@gmail.com',
  password: '$2b$10$ro4FIO40.3Nwe52RFq/leepH906HvIHYW5A3XrTGfNXcUSIfsx0Bq',
  createdAt: 2020-03-23T14:27:47.820Z,
  updatedAt: 2020-03-23T14:28:10.290Z,
  __v: 1 }
```

It looks like the hashed password has changed.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your blog post method is effecting your user record somehow.

Try making a new user, logging in, checking the user record looks normal.

Then make a post as that user and rather than checking for the post, check the user record for differences before you made the post. I'd expect that something from the post update is changing something in the user record by mistake.

Comment: yeah it's pushing the `objectId` of the post that the user has made into the posts array that the user has. 

it was done for using populate method. But how does that affect the login method? it's only checking for email and password, right?

Comment: Hey, I updated my question. Turns out the password is changing.